# Nginx SSL + Apache2: Сервер не отдает файлы, генерируемые на лету.

Tags: apache, nginx

В общем ситуация странная. На сервере настроена связка Nginx + Apache2, Nginx разруливает статические файлы и с недавнего времени на нем настроен SSL. Проблема в том, клиенту не отдаются на скачивание CSV-файл, который генерирует Apache2 "на лету" средствами PHP. В какую сторону копать? Конфиг хоста:

```
server {    listen          443;    server_name     example.org *.example.org;    access_log      /var/log/nginx/dev_host_ssl.log;    error_log       /var/log/nginx/dev_host_ssl.err;    ssl                             on;    ssl_certificate                 /home/cert/ruelsoft-org.crt;    ssl_certificate_key             /home/cert/ruelsoft-org.key;    ssl_session_timeout             10m;    ssl_protocols                   SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;    ssl_ciphers           ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers       on;    #далее идет описание location'ов
```

Конфиг proxy.conf:

```
proxy_redirect                  off;proxy_set_header                Host $host;proxy_set_header                X-Real-IP $remote_addr;proxy_set_header                X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;client_max_body_size            500m;client_body_buffer_size         128k;proxy_connect_timeout           90;proxy_send_timeout              90;proxy_read_timeout              90;proxy_buffer_size               4k;proxy_buffers                   4 32k;proxy_busy_buffers_size         64k;proxy_temp_file_write_size      64k;
```

Ну и nginx.conf:

```
user                    www-data;worker_processes        8;error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log;pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;events {    worker_connections      1024;}http {    include         /etc/nginx/mime.types;    default_type    application/octet-stream;    access_log      /var/log/nginx/access.log;    sendfile        on;    tcp_nopush      on;    client_max_body_size    500m;    keepalive_timeout       2;    tcp_nodelay             on;    gzip    on;    gzip_comp_level         3;    gzip_proxied            any;    gzip_types              text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/$    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;    upstream apache2 {            server  127.0.0.1:8080;    }    upstream mercurial {            server  127.0.0.1:8081;    }    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;}
```

Comment: Вопрос можно закрывать. На самом деле проблема была из-за использования OAuth между приложением и главным сайтом. Пришлось решить использованием Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вынесено из комментария.

---

На самом деле проблема была из-за использования *OAuth* между приложением и главным сайтом. Пришлось решить использованием *Ajax*.

Answer (score 0):

Может php отдает неверные заголовки?Попробуйте добавить в php

```
header("Content-type: application/csv");header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");header("Pragma: no-cache");header("Expires: 0");
```